# Inital Y Axi Rotation after applying THREE.DeviceOrientationControls on Camera Object

Tags: three.js

my scene has a simple Cube on position: {x: 0, y:0, z: -20} and the camera has the inital position {x: 0, y:0, z: 0} and rotation: {x: 0, y:0, z: 0}. at this point my cube is visible in “north” direction. now when i apply THREE.DeviceOrientationControls on my camera object the camera rotates on the Y Axi by 90 degrees. Now iam able to rotate the camera by rotating the mobile device but the origin has changed (“north” is now “west”). i would to keep my inital direction after the THREE.DeviceOrientationControls apply. how could i reach that? I noticed there is a a variable in the DeviceOrientationControls.js:

this.alphaOffset = 0; // radians

but changes to this variable seems not work properly.

**UPDATE:**

i have attached the source code.

[This is the Scene before the DeviceOrientationControls is applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG6MW.jpg)

[This is the Scene after DeviceOrientationControls is applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6bbd.jpg)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 
 var camera, scene, renderer, controls,
 northMesh,southMesh,westMesh,eastMesh,
 northMeshDiv,southMeshDiv,westMeshDiv,eastMeshDiv,
 northMeshLabel,southMeshLabel,westMeshLabel,eastMeshLabel;

 init();
 animate();
 
 function init() {
  
  
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
  
    
  setTimeout(function(){
   controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls( camera );
  }, 3000);
  

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 ); // the default
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
  
  
  northMesh = new THREE.Mesh(  new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true } ) );
  northMesh.position.x = 0;
  northMesh.position.y = 0;
  northMesh.position.z = -20;
  scene.add( northMesh );
  northMeshDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
  northMeshDiv.className = 'label';
  northMeshDiv.style.marginTop = '-1em';
  northMeshDiv.style.color = '#ff0000';
  northMeshDiv.textContent = 'NORTH';
  northMeshLabel = new THREE.CSS2DObject( northMeshDiv );
  northMeshLabel.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
  northMesh.add( northMeshLabel );
  
  eastMesh = new THREE.Mesh(  new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, wireframe: true } ) );
  eastMesh.position.x = 20;
  eastMesh.position.y = 0;
  eastMesh.position.z = 0;
  scene.add( eastMesh );
  eastMeshDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
  eastMeshDiv.className = 'label';
  eastMeshDiv.style.marginTop = '-1em';
  eastMeshDiv.style.color = '#00ff00';
  eastMeshDiv.textContent = 'EAST';
  eastMeshLabel = new THREE.CSS2DObject( eastMeshDiv );
  eastMeshLabel.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
  eastMesh.add( eastMeshLabel );
  
  
  southMesh = new THREE.Mesh(  new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff00ff, wireframe: true } ) );
  southMesh.position.x = 0;
  southMesh.position.y = 0;
  southMesh.position.z = 20;
  scene.add( southMesh );
  southMeshDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
  southMeshDiv.className = 'label';
  southMeshDiv.style.marginTop = '-1em';
  southMeshDiv.style.color = '#ff00ff';
  southMeshDiv.textContent = 'SOUTH';
  southMeshLabel = new THREE.CSS2DObject( southMeshDiv );
  southMeshLabel.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
  southMesh.add( southMeshLabel );
  
  
  westMesh = new THREE.Mesh(  new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff, wireframe: true } ) );
  westMesh.position.x = -20;
  westMesh.position.y = 0;
  westMesh.position.z = 0;
  scene.add( westMesh );
  westMeshDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
  westMeshDiv.className = 'label';
  westMeshDiv.style.marginTop = '-1em';
  westMeshDiv.style.color = '#0000ff';
  westMeshDiv.textContent = 'WEST';
  westMeshLabel = new THREE.CSS2DObject( westMeshDiv );
  westMeshLabel.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
  westMesh.add( westMeshLabel );

  
     

  labelRenderer = new THREE.CSS2DRenderer();
  labelRenderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
  document.body.appendChild( labelRenderer.domElement );

  
  //FPS
  var container = document.getElementById( 'stats' );
  stats = new Stats();
  container.appendChild( stats.dom );

  
  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
 }

 function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 }

 function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  
  if(controls) controls.update();
  stats.update();

  render();
 }

 function render() {

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  labelRenderer.render( scene, camera );
 }
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title></title>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        
    </head>
    <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/CSS2DRenderer.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/WebGL.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/stats.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/DeviceOrientationControls.js"></script>
  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        
        <div id="stats"></div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: North is now west? Is the orientation lock enabled on your device? Does your device work as expected when viewing this example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=device#misc_controls_deviceorientation ? Also, you should add your actual code, so we can see if it's a problem in there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I hope the Sourcecode is helful. the rotation is working perfect on my device, but the orientation has changed (the "north" cube is not visible anymore after i apply the DeviceOrientation Controller). I would to keep my inital direction.